# Error in axis.set in matplotlib

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, syntax

Learning Python, but got a syntax error and not sure why...

When writing a line of code in Python, I am getting a syntax error:

`ax_lr.set(xlabel=("Unemployment_rate"), xlim=(0.0,0.20), xticklabels=([0.00, 0.05, 0.10, 0.15, 0.20], rotation=90))`

However, when I remove the `rotation=90` and set it separately, the issue goes away:

```
ax_lr.set(xlabel=("Unemployment_rate"), xlim=(0.0,0.20), xticklabels=([0.00, 0.05, 0.10, 0.15, 0.20]))
ax_lr.set_xticklabels(rotation=90)
```

Why does the first example have a syntax error?

Answer (score 1):

Because your parentheses are mismatched.  Remove the parentheses after `xticklables`.

Comment: Which parentheses are you referring to? After rotation=90 or the one after that? The first is to close the xticklabels settings and the second is to close the entire .set